# Drawing a binary tree in tikz

Tags: tikz-trees

I tried to do this tree for the first time and I used this code but appears an error. How can I correct these errors?

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUUqN.png)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta}
    \usegdlibrary{trees}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
    \graph[binary tree layout]{
      a -> {   
        b -> { 
          c -> { 
            d -> { e, f }, 
            g 
          }, 
        h -> { i, j }
        },
        k -> {
          l -> {
            m -> { n, o },
            p -> { q, r }
          }, 
          s -> {
            v -> {w, x},
            y -> {z}
          }
        }
      }
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! I do not get an error when I compile your code with `lualatex` on my updated TeXLive2019 installation.

Comment: oh yes i found my mistake thanks alot